# Show a series of Dynamic JSON/Dictionaries in a WPF DataGrid, just like the values from a SQL select query

Tags: wpf, json, dynamic, dictionary, datagrid

I've been trying and testing to get this working: binding a series of dictionaries to a datagrid. In such a way that it is like coming from a database. So not showing only 2 columns or any of the metadata columns such as count and toStrings.

**The scenario:**
I'm downloading JSON based upon a URL. The JSON values come in various forms, but i can transform them to a dictionary or any other type that has keys and values. Each URL is a single line / a single record, this i want to show the values with the same keys in the datagrid from multiple URL's.

I've tried dozens of possible solutions, such as expando objects, dropping the JObject directly in the Gridview, Working with arrays, single lists etc. None gets close to what i want. What i want is: automatic column detection and displaying the right values for the JSON that is loaded.

For example this json: {"x":"a", "y":"b","z":"c"} should be represented in the GridView like this:

```
 x  | y   | z  
---------------
 a    b     c
```

When another JSON-returning part of the code (another URL) is loaded, it should look like this:

```
 x  | y   | z  
---------------
 a    b     c
 e    f     g
```

**Current code:**
What i have now is:

```
Dictionary < string, string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary < string, string>();
JObject parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< JObject>(jSonPart);

foreach (var x in parsed)
{
    MyDictionary.Add(x.Key,x.Value.Value<String>());
}
outputJson.Items.Add(MyDictionary);

// list of dictionaries. 
_jsonObjects.Add(MyDictionary.ToList());
```

Here is some assigning i use:

```
List < List < KeyValuePair < String,String > > >  _jsonObjects = new List < List < KeyValuePair<String,String> > > ();
outputJson.ItemsSource = _jsonObjects;
```